# Responsive design in Android with external images?

Tags: android, image, layout, interface

I'm developing an Android App with an interface formed by external images. The size of all images is exported in pixels and when I try to test the application, it looks different in all devices.

What I'm doing bad?

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Control">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn1state"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn2state" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn3state" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn4state" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn5state"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn6state" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn7state" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn8state" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn5"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn9state"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn10"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn10state" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn11"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn10"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn11state" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn12"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn11"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn11"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn12state"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn13"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn9"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn13state"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn14"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn13"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn13"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn14state"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn15"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn14"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn14"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn15state"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn16"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn15"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn15"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn16state"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

That's a sample of my code.

In another 7" it was working well, but this tablet has different resolution.

Should I have to work in dp with image sizes or what I have to do to adapt it? When I put all images in the different folders (drawable-ldpi...) it looks always. Any suggerence please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to manage image dimensions on android apps and be sure to keep under control the behavior of the images is to use DensityPixel.

- **px** is one pixel;
- **sp** is scale-independent pixels;
- **dip==dp** is Density-independent pixels.

The best way is to use:

- **sp** for font sizes;
- **dp** for everything else.

In addition, use the normal, large, xlarge different RES to manage each different resolution for images.

You can also define one single layout for each different size screen; Let me know, if you need to go in this way; i can link something useful.

For general knowledge, from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension:

> **px** Pixels - corresponds to actual pixels on the screen.
>
> **in** Inches - based on the physical size of the screen.
>
> **mm** Millimeters - based on the physical size of the screen.
>
> **pt** Points - 1/72 of an inch based on the physical size of the screen.
>
> **dp** Density-independent Pixels - an abstract unit that is based on the physical density of the screen. These units are relative to a 160
> dpi screen, so one dp is one pixel on a 160 dpi screen. The ratio of
> dp-to-pixel will change with the screen density, but not necessarily
> in direct proportion. Note: The compiler accepts both "dip" and "dp",
> though "dp" is more consistent with "sp".
>
> **sp** Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you
> use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for
> both the screen density and user's preference.

Comment: The application will usually run on 7" tablets, the problem is that they are low-cost tablets and the resolution may go from 480x800 or 1024x600 in the best case. Non usuall resolutions for tablets I know. So my problem is that I have to export my images in dp. And in code, I have to work with % or something like that?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to export images in DP; i never did it. And i don't think you can manage the dimension in the code with %; i never tried.In your question you wrote: "Should I have to work in dp with image sizes..." so i understand that you didn't tested it. Try to go with DP and test the result.

Comment: It's probably impossible, but then it's all correct? I work with dp in code and its not working anyway... I will try to put all images in all folders. The layout.xml has to be in all folders too?

Comment: No, the Layout doesn't have to be in those folders. Please find here the official information regarding the different screen management [different screen management](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Comment: The same, images look too bigger for all devices:
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Maybe for this but I don't know how to fix.

Comment: Did you tried [scaling the images](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)?

Comment: Omg, just tried before seeing this. It works, I've dona a tableLayout and I put images inside each cell and then scaleType= fitCenter. Thank you very much man! 

The other problem was that I created a RelativeLayout and the distence between each object was in dp, sam dp in all devices. ERROR! haha

PROBLEM SOLVED.

Comment: Perfect!! Enjoy your app!!

Answer (score 0):

To cater for different screen sizes, we define different layout files for a variety of different screen sizes (namely: normal, large, xlarge). This way Android resizes your application to fit the current screen size.

However I have also read that this way of doing the layout is deprecated. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) it is stated that we should rather use the new configuration qualifier to define the smallest availabdefine the smallest available width required by your layout resources. For example, if your multi-pane tablet layout requires at least 600dp of screen width, you should place it in layout-sw600dp/.

I hope this helps a little atleast.

Comment: I heard about this, the problem is that doesn't matter the name of the folder, my application always looks the same. But don't know if it's for images or for code.

Comment: Well the different layout files (containing TextViews or ImageViews and how these views are handled i.e. crop etc) should be different. Each resizing certain elements pertaining to the type of device the application is running on.

Comment: So, I have to export all images for each size and rewrite a new xml for each resolution?

Comment: I put:
android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

So I will have to change this values every time, right?

Comment: Yes so for different screen sizes you would customise each layout file. Each layout file will probably have the same elements but the sizes etc would be different. Also, the ImageView has ways of dealing with different image sizes which you should maybe look into.